# How to stop Kendo UI MultiSelect from opening on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, onclick

Being more specific, here [dojo sandbox](https://dojo.telerik.com/AreFom) where i want to make custom click listener for tagList without opening dropdown list, but neither preventDefault nor stopPropagation achieving it, even though selected node is first on event's path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `open` event handler to the options object and use `preventDefault` there, if the clicked element is the `tagList`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/grouping">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      
.k-multiselect .k-multiselect-wrap {
 display: flex;
}
.k-multiselect .k-multiselect-wrap ul {
 counter-reset: multiselect-counter;
 display: inline-flex;
 padding-left: 5px;
}
.k-multiselect .k-multiselect-wrap ul li {
 counter-increment: multiselect-counter;
 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
}
.k-multiselect .k-multiselect-wrap ul::after {
  content: counter(multiselect-counter) ' chosen';
  display: inline;
  align-self: center;
  padding: 2px 4px 0 0;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(103, 103, 103);
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>

        <div id="example">

            <div class="demo-section k-content">
                <h4>Customers</h4>
                <input id="customers" style="width: 100%;" />
            </div>

            <script>
               function checkInputs(elements) {
                  elements.each(function() {
                    let element = $(this),
                        input = element.children('input');
                    input.prop('checked', element.hasClass('k-state-selected'));
                  });
                };
              
               let open = false;
              
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#customers").kendoMultiSelect({
                        dataTextField: "name",
                        dataValueField: "id",
                        height: 400,
            autoClose: false,
                        change: function() {
                          var items = this.ul.find('li');
                          checkInputs(items);
                        },
                       open: function(e) {
                           if (!open) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                            }
                           open = false;
                        },
                       tagTemplate: "<div onclick=''>TEST</div>",
            itemTemplate: '<input type="checkbox"/><span class="k-state-default"> #:data.name#</span>',
                        dataSource: [{"name": "a", "id": 1, "group": 1}, {"name": "h", "id": 14, "group": 1},
                                    {"name": "b", "id": 2, "group": 2}, {"name": "k", "id": 13, "group": 1},
                                    {"name": "c", "id": 3, "group": 2}, {"name": "l", "id": 12, "group": 2},
                                    {"name": "d", "id": 4, "group": 2}, {"name": "m", "id": 11, "group": 2},
                                    {"name": "e", "id": 5, "group": 3}, {"name": "n", "id": 10, "group": 2},
                                    {"name": "f", "id": 6, "group": 2}, {"name": "o", "id": 9, "group": 3},
                                    {"name": "g", "id": 7, "group": 2}, {"name": "p", "id": 8, "group": 3}]
                    });
                   $("#customers").data('kendoMultiSelect').dataSource.group({"field":"group"});
                   
                   $("#customers").data('kendoMultiSelect').wrapper.on('click', function(e){
                       if (e.target.id !== "customers_taglist") {
                          open = true;
                          $("#customers").data('kendoMultiSelect').open();
                       }
                    });
                  
                });
            </script>
            
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then it prevents it from opening at all, i need to stop it just for click on tagList node.